# GIT: see file list and their versions

Tags: git, github

How to list the files in current directory along with their versions??

ie I want to see something like this:

```
foo.c         @ cdc8bc8
Makefile      @ ab93df1
foo.h         @ 92af931
```

Comment: In git, the commit id applies to the whole tree, not individual files.  Except in rare cases when you've checked out a copy of a file from another commit, all the files will be from the same one...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will get you close, but I'm not sure there's a way to do exactly what you want...

```
git log --pretty=format:"%C(yellow)%h%Cred%d\\ %Creset%s%Cblue\\ [%cn]" --decorate --numstat
```

This is from an article of [must have git aliases](http://durdn.com/blog/2012/11/22/must-have-git-aliases-advanced-examples/) - check that page out - a bunch of cool examples.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `git log` or `gitk` to see the history of your files.

Answer (score 0):

For all the files in the current directory:

```
git log --stat .
```

For just a particular file:

```
git log -- myfile.txt
```